Can't connect external nodes to Main percona replicaset cluster
I replicated an openshift cluster that runs mongodb with Percona operator. I added the unmanaged cluster's nodes to the Main cluster and exposed them with Nodeport:
 replsets:
- size: 3
  expose:
    enabled: true
    exposeType: NodePort
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 300m
      memory: 0.5G
    requests:
      cpu: 300m
      memory: 0.5G
  externalNodes:
    - host: 10.115.199.188
      port: 30320
      priority: 0
      votes: 0
    - host: 10.151.44.88
      port: 32655
      priority: 0
      votes: 0
    - host: 10.198.42.20
      port: 30598
      priority: 0
      votes: 0

But when i'm opening a session in the db i see that the external nodes don't communicate with the main cluster and the reasons might be different on each member:
    {
  _id: 12,
  name: '10.115.199.188:30320',
  health: 0,
  state: 8,
  stateStr: '(not reachable/healthy)',
  uptime: 0,
  optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long("-1") },
  optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long("-1") },
  optimeDate: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  optimeDurableDate: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2024-07-15T13:47:56.323Z"),
  lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  pingMs: Long("0"),
  lastHeartbeatMessage: 'Error connecting to 10.103.189.188:32320 :: caused by :: No route to host',
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  infoMessage: '',
  configVersion: -1,
  configTerm: -1
},
{
  _id: 13,
  name: '10.151.44.88:32655',
  health: 0,
  state: 8,
  stateStr: '(not reachable/healthy)',
  uptime: 0,
  optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long("-1") },
  optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long("-1") },
  optimeDate: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  optimeDurableDate: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2024-07-15T13:47:56.964Z"),
  lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  pingMs: Long("0"),
  lastHeartbeatMessage: "Couldn't get a connection within the time limit",
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  infoMessage: '',
  configVersion: -1,
  configTerm: -1
}

Any ideas why is this happening?

not really. there is no firewall on the nodes
